# Error on SCSS conversion when building the website with Hugo in Visual Code

Tags: css, sass, build, hugo

I have a website which is in development by using Hugo and VC and it works perfectly when I'm running it locally by using `npm run dev`

When I'm trying to build the site by putting in `hugo` it gives me an error which states it can't build because of;

```
Error: error building site: POSTCSS: failed to transform "css/style.css" (text/css): 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I can't find the change that happened before, checked all settings, but no luck. I also tried to find articles on SO and internet, but it is not the same problem or the right interpretation is too hard for me.

I'm using this theme: [Hugo Biztrox Theme](https://docs.gethugothemes.com/biztrox/)

Anyone who would like to direct me into the right path, literally?
Greets, Merijn